# Reaction of 1,3 diphenyl propane with alkaline potassium permanganate followed by acidification

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Will the product be just benzoic acid?
If yes how does this reaction proceed
Normally alkyl group substituted benzene ring seems to give benzoic acid irrespective of chain length
However is it true when 2 benzene rings are connected

Mechanism is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to get two equivalents of benzoic acid from oxidation of both benzylic sites based on the summary [here](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/reaction-guide/oxidation-of-aromatic-alkanes-with-kmno4-to-give-carboxylic-acids/). The mechanism of this oxidative process is AFAIK not completely understood.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please accept it.